# Diophantine Equations about triangular numbers

Tags: number-theory

Let $T_{n}$ denote the $n^{th}$ triangular number.For example, $1$, $1+2$, $1+2+3$, $1+2+3+4$ and so on to infinite. 
Is it true that whenever a positive integer $v$ is not a perfect square then the equation $v T_{x}=T_{y}$ has infinitely many integer solutions for positive integers $x$ and $y$. If it is true-then why or prove that in brief?

Comment: I think you get a pell equation

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/855300/distribution-of-integer-solution-pairs-x-y-for-2x2-y2-y/855342#855342

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/279317/sum-of-two-consecutive-squares-equals-difference-of-two-consecutive-cubes/279390#279390

Comment: Exactly, @Jorge Fernandez.   I am getting the Pell's Equation $(2y+1)^{2}-v(2x+1)^{2}=1-v$. But my proof is getting long and long through out  and I personally feel that it's not easy unless we do little higher level integrals and summations. I may post my approach but my proof is still incomplete, in explaing the the bounds.

Comment: For the solution of the equation Pell.  $X^2-vY^2=1-v$ You can use these formulas.  https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1048219

Comment: Thanks everyone. I find the solutions finally avoiding complex stuffs(complex ideas). My idea is $(a_{1}, b_{1})$ be the initial solution to $a^{2}-vb^{2}=1$ then with the set $(2y+1)+(2x+1)\sqrt{k} = (1+\sqrt{k})(a_{1}+b_{1}\sqrt{k})^{j}$ we are done

Comment: And where $v=k$ and also Where $(a_{1},b_{1})$ are opposite parity we obtain infinitely many positive integral solutions $(x, y) $.