# Can $T(n)=T(m)\cdot k^2$ have more than $2$ solutions in positive integers?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

Suppose , $k>1$ is a positive integer.

Consider the equation $$T(n)=T(m)\cdot k^2$$ where $T(n)$ denotes the $n$-th triangle number, so $T(n)=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$. If we multiply with $8$ and add $1$ , we get $$4n^2+4n+1=(4m^2+4m)k^2+1=(4m^2+4m+1)k^2+1-k^2$$

Hence $$(2n+1)^2-(2m+1)^2\cdot k^2=1-k^2$$

With $u:=2n+1$ and $v:=2m+1$ , this can be written as $$(u-kv)(u+kv)=1-k^2$$

This shows that for every positive integer $k>1$, there are only finite many solutions in positive integers $m$ and $n$. For some $k$, there are $2$ solutions, for example $k=96030$ allows $m=2$ and $m=24007$ , $k=526890$ allows $m=3$ and $m=131722$ , $k=1866294$ allows $m=4$ and $m=466573$.

> Is there a $k$, such there are more than $2$ solutions in positive integers ? If yes, what is the smallest such $k$ ?

Comment: Inspired by this question : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2498447/diophantine-equations-about-triangular-numbers

Comment: Your solutions seem to be related to Chebyshev polynomials, like $u=T_n(x),\;k=U_{n-1}(x),\;v=x$ for arbitrary $n,\;x$.

Comment: We have $(2mk+k)^2-k^2-(2n+1)^2=-1$. Then, [The diophantine equation X^2 - Y^2 - Z^2 = +- 1](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/114707/the-diophantine-equation-x2-y2-z2-1) might help.

Comment: Another thing that I would like to know : Is there an easy criterion for which $k$ we have a solution ? For $k\equiv 2\mod 4$  and $k\ge 6$, there is always a solution, but what about the other $k$ ?

Comment: You are right. For $k=4t+2$, $(m,n)=(t,4t^2+4t)$ is a solution. By the way, as Ivan Neretin comments, all the values of $k$ you wrote are included in OEIS [A242850](http://oeis.org/A242850). So, they are of the form $32(2N+1)^2-32(2N+1)^3+6(2N+1)$ though I'm not sure how this helps.